# Как подключить Vue без npm?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Vue нужен на проекте который изначально написан на PHP. Очень изолированно нужен в одном месте для чата. Пытаюсь подключить:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="/js/chat/main.js"></script>
```

И в main.js

```
import Chat from './Chat'

new Vue({
    el: '#chat',
    template: '<chat/>',
    components: {Chat},
})
```

Так выдает 404 на `import Chat from './Chat'`. Если же добавить расширение `import Chat from './Chat.vue'` то пишет ошибку:

```
Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

Answer (score 0):

Подключите в Head а скрипт с vue в той части сайта где требуется

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
```

Comment: Какая разница в head он или в футере? CDN подключен так или иначе перед моим скриптом.

Comment: Да ты не переживай так сильно , не  увидел я той части где ты подключаешь vue , проверь путь до js файла. Либо тут посмотри https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47403478/es6-modules-in-local-files-the-server-responded-with-a-non-javascript-mime-typ

Comment: Путь верный. По ссылке нет решения для Vue. Это же не обычный JS файл...

Answer (score 0):

Насчет импорта. Он обязателен? Насколько я знаю, поддержка модулей в браузере далеко не полная.

Далее, вы подключаете обычную js версию Vue,  не модульную.

Установите модульную версию как указано в документации, это должно сработать. https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#CDN

```
<script type="module">
  import Vue from  'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.esm.browser.js'
</script>
```

Вроде бы напрямую без компиляции SFC использовать нельзя, это же не js.  Этот ответ вам должен помочь https://stackoverflow.com/q/43896319/9047572

Comment: Ну а как без импорта то? Есть другие способы? Я их не знаю. Этот способ подключения тоже не помог - ошибка осталась.

Comment: Обновил ответ. Посмотрите

Comment: Ладно, неважно. Пускай будет npm. Создал другую тему: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1261048/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-vue-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be