# Как подключить Vue на сайт отдельно?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm

Мне нужен Vue для одного модального окна. Очень изолированно. Это не SPA. Я воспользовался Vue UI и создал проект в папке web. Но не знаю что надо подключить на странице чтобы заработало... Он компилирует релизную минифицированную версию в папку dist, хотя я запускаю команду `serve`, а мне надо dev версию. Пытался подключать файл src/main.js, но опять получил ошибку `main.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`. Никак не могу понять какой файл мне подключать для отладочной версии...

Comment: `Cannot use import ` имеется ввиду вы пытаетесь вызвать `require` в main.js, если да то вам нужно настроить babel для обращения через require. Так же в файле package.json есть информация о скриптах запуска приложения, `npm run serve` и тд

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно собрать ваш проект в один файл и подключить его как любую другую стороннюю библиотеку.

Во Vue.js это делается или ручками или при помощи библиотеки vue-custom-element
Делаете ваш **main.js** плюс-минус вот таким

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import store from './store/index'

import vueCustomElement from 'vue-custom-element'

Vue.use(vueCustomElement)
App.store = store
Vue.customElement('super-widget', App)
```

**public/index.html** меняете `<div id="app"></div>` на `<super-widget></super-widget>`

И вот тут проверяете, как у вас дела - запускаете dev сборку. Все должно работать как работало. Если это так и есть, то это полный улёт!

Осталось сделать так, чтобы в продакшн сборке у вас был один js + один css (если у вас есть стили конечно) файл. Для этого в vue.config.js вносим вот такой блок

```
  chainWebpack: (config) => {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
      config.optimization.delete('splitChunks');
    }
  },
```

Все, запускаем сборку, получаем два файлика - поздравляю вы сделали свой первый виджет на vue.js.